# Find all header files in all sub-directories

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I am trying to use any header from my `include` folder in any source file in my `src` folder. Right now, I am doing `"#include ../../include/subfolder/file.h"` or `#include "../include/otherfile.h"`to get access to my header files, but this is very verbose, and anytime I do a directory restructure, I have to go back and change every reference to the affected header files. I would like to just be able to do `#include "file.h"` from any source file, but I can't seem to do it. Doing `-Iinclude` or `-Iinclude/` can't find the headers in `subfolder` for some reason. Changing my include statement to `#include <file.h>` also doesn't work. What can I do to fix this?

I have a project layout that looks like this:

```
Makefile

include
    subfolder
        file.h
    otherfile.h

src
    subfolder
        file.c
    otherfile.c
```

My Makefile looks like this:

```
TARGET = program
LIBS = -llibs
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -g -Iinclude/

.PHONY: default all clean

default: $(TARGET)
all: default

OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(shell find . -name '*.c'))
HEADERS = $(shell find . -name '*.h')

%.o: %.c $(HEADERS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

.PRECIOUS: $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -Wall $(LIBS) -o $@

clean:
    find . -type f -name '*.o' -exec rm {} +
    find . -type f -name $(TARGET) -exec rm {} +
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can auto-generate the include dir flags simply enough:

```
 INC_DIRS := $(shell find include -type d)
 C_INC_FLAGS := $(addprefix -I,$(INC_DIRS))

 %.o: %.c $(HEADERS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(C_INC_FLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Note, that most systems have a maximum line length (usually around 64k), so if you have LOTS of directories, you may have to worry that you exceed the max line length (at which point you pipe the dirs to a file and include with `@file`...)

Also, this doesn't work if you autogenerate new directories in your include directory through your make rules, as those directories will not be there when you populate `INC_DIRS` the first time around.

Answer (score 2):

Simple, just use

```
#include <myheader.h>
```

and pass the relevant directory to the compiler through the `-I` switch.

For instance, if *myheader.h* was in *include/subfolder* then,

```
$(CC) -Iinclude/subfolder
```

will work.

Note that you must also *include* the subfolder in the `-I` argument because only the top level directory is scanned for headers.

Comment: It doesn't find all of the header files in all of the subdirectories. I would have to do `-Iinclude/subfolder` for every subfolder.

Comment: @MuhammadYojer Well, that's what you have to do. The alternative is to put the folder in the `#include` statement itself. Like `#include "subfolder/file.h"`, and only use `-Iinclude` as the compiler switch.

Comment: @NikosC. There's no other alternative?

Comment: Yes, use a complete full featured build system, like [autotools](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Autotools-Introduction.html) or [cmake](https://cmake.org/). That way you don't need to worry about passing the values to the compiler yourself. And it's a lot easier to change and fix them (*it's more maintainable*).

Comment: @MuhammadYojer Well, if you're writing makefiles by hand, you have to deal with this stuff by hand too. The alternative is to use a build system like Meson or CMake instead, and they will automate much of this. You'll still have to tell them the directories the headers are in, but they will take care of the compiler flags.

Comment: Perhaps `#include <myheader.h>` --> `#include "myheader.h"`

Comment: @MuhammadYojer If you learn something like *cmake* you can then, use wildcards for subfolders.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi Maybe I'll try it.